# Write file to disk from blob in electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am creating an Electron Application in which I am recording data from webcam and desktop, at the end of the recording session, I want to save the data to a file in the background. I do not know how to write the data from a blob to a file directly. Any suggestions?
Below is my current handling for MediaRecord Stop event.

```
this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {                                      
       var blob = new Blob(this.chunks,                                      
                           { 'type' : 'video/mp4; codecs=H.264' });                                                       
       var fs = require('fs');                                               
       var fr = new FileReader();                                            
       var data = null;                                                      
       fr.onload = () => {                                                   
           data = fr.result;                                                 
           fs.writeFile("test.mp4", data, err => {                           
               if(err) {                                                     
                   return console.log(err);                                  
               }                                                             
               console.log("The file was saved!");                           
           });                                                               
       };                                                                    
       fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);                                           
   }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it using `FileReader` and `Buffer`.

In the renderer process, send the event to the main process to save the file with the buffer:

```
function saveBlob(blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function() {
        if (reader.readyState == 2) {
            var buffer = new Buffer(reader.result)
            ipcRenderer.send(SAVE_FILE, fileName, buffer)
            console.log(`Saving ${JSON.stringify({ fileName, size: blob.size })}`)
        }
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
}
```

Get back the confirmation:

```
ipcRenderer.on(SAVED_FILE, (event, path) => {
    console.log("Saved file " + path)
})
```

(SAVE_FILE and SAVED_FILE are static strings containing event name)

and in the main process:

```
ipcMain.on(SAVE_FILE, (event, path, buffer) => {
    outputFile(path, buffer, err => {
        if (err) {
            event.sender.send(ERROR, err.message)
        } else {
            event.sender.send(SAVED_FILE, path)
        }
    })
})
```

outputFile is from ['fs-extra'](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/outputFile.md)

Handling node operations in main process is preferred. See Electron Security suggestions.

If you do want to not use main process, you can use ['electron-remote'](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-remote) to create background processes to write the file. Additionally, you can invoke `ffmpeg` in the background process to compress/encode the file into different format.

Comment: Sorry for coming to you a bit late. But haven't had time to try your solution until today. And it is working well, thank you.
I only have one more issue in the output file. When I try to play it with any video player, it does not show the length of the video correctly, it shows only it has 1 sec of video, and even that the 1 second ends it keeps playing the video fully. but I can not forward, backward if the video, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Yes I have the same issue. I am not sure why it is this way. Someone familiar with codecs and their playback can explain it. I end up re-rendering it using ffmpeg to mp4 after which it shows it correctly.

Comment: The duration issue is a problem with MediaRecorder. If you transcode using ffmpeg, it should correct itself.

Comment: Please, post the content for variables SAVE_FILE and SAVED_FILE

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes those are arbitrary, you can designate whatever strings you want to use for event names in interprocess communication, see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main for more info

Comment: Would a  ```SharedArrayBuffer``` with a RingBuffer be useful to speed the process? Seen a ffmpeg worker stdin encoder at ffmpeg.js that uses such shared buffers between the WebPage and a Worker. Is it worth or possible to do it this way in Electron? Or even the same as that shared regular buffer?