# Saving OffscreenCanvas content to disk as PNG in Electron

Tags: html5-canvas, electron

I'm using canvg to render SVG on a Canvas and download it as PNG from browser. Here's a working typescript code 
snippet based on their docs.

```
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(this.width, this.height);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx!, this.svg.innerHTML, presets.offscreen());

    // Render only first frame, ignoring animations and mouse.
    await v.render();

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob();
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = pngUrl;

    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = pngUrl;
    a.download = "svgexport.png";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
```

However I want to get this working in Electron. Instead of downloading the PNG, I want to write it to the disk using `fs` module. I tried several ways of writing the `blob` content to a PNG file, however the saved file is not a valid PNG file. I also tried electron's `nativeImage`. But none of its APIs (`createFromBuffer`, `createFromBitmap`, `createFromDataURL`) give the desired result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write file to disk from blob in electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562192/write-file-to-disk-from-blob-in-electron-application)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a round about way to accomplish this. From the blob that I get from OffscreenCanvas, I create an `Image` object, then render it to a `canvas`, then I can write the data URL from that canvas to a file on disk and it gives me a valid PNG. Here's the code

```
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(this.width, this.height);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx!, this.svg.innerHTML, presets.offscreen());

    // Render only first frame, ignoring animations and mouse.
    await v.render();

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob();
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        context!.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        let dataURL = (canvas as HTMLCanvasElement).toDataURL();
        const base64Data = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
        fs.writeFile("test5.png", base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    img.src = pngUrl;
```

I would like to see if someone has a better suggestion.